# exclude certain email country domains using jquery validation plugin

Tags: jquery, regex, validation, plugins

I'm trying to add a custom rule to the jquery validation plugin where it will prevent the person from entering in an email address with a country domain of either "cu, ir, kp, sd, sv". For example, the user would not be able to enter johnsmith@yahoo.cu or johnsmith@yahoo.kp.

I tried creating a regular expression but its still allowing me to enter in the any email country domain.

Here's what I have so far:

```
$.validator.addMethod(
                    "wrong_domain",
                    function (value,element,params) {
                        var emaildomain = new RegExp("(/cu$/) | (/ir$/) | (/kp$/) | (/sd$/) | (/sy$/)");
                        if (emaildomain.test(value)) return false;                      
                    },
                    'Not an acceptable email' );
```

I don't have any errors in the browser console. I'm not very familiar with regular expressions, so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to create multiple regular expressions in that `RegExp` constructor. Each set of slashes (`/`) is intended to begin a new regex, but you can't do that in the JS constructor. Instead, give this a go:

```
var emaildomain = /\.(cu|ir|kp|sd|sy)$/i;
if (emaildomain.test(value)) return false;
```

Or just cut out the middleman:

```
if (/\.(cu|ir|kp|sd|sy)$/i.test(value)) return false;
```

Or if you still want to use the object constructor:

```
var emaildomain = new RegExp("\\.(cu|ir|kp|sd|sy)$", "i");
if (emaildomain.test(value)) return false;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help @jakerella. I tried all three of your solutions and its still allowing me to enter any country domain. Do I need to change the 'i' character? This is what I just used:

$.validator.addMethod(
"wrong_domain",
function (value,element,params) {
var emaildomain = /\.(cu|ir|kp|sd|sy)$/i;
if (emaildomain.test(value)) return false;         
},
'Not an acceptable email' );

Comment: Then it looks like the issue is not with the regex, but with validation plugin or your implementation of it. That regex works for the email addresses in your post (you can check it in Firebug/Dev tools/etc). Are you sure that function is being called? Maybe you could add a `debugger` or `console.log()` statement in there to see that it is hit.

Comment: And by the way, the `i` at the end of the regex makes it case insensitive. I'm guessing you don't want to allow "...@YAHOO.CU" either.

Comment: I figured out what was the problem. This custom validation rule was interferring with another custom validation rule I was applying to the email field. I also had to change the field type from email to text.